# R言語の外積演算関数 outer() を利用して、任意の自作関数（ガウス核関数 GaussianKernel() ）の z軸の値を求める際の関数の挙動について

Tags: r, 機械学習

R言語の外積演算関数 `outer()`を利用してガウス核関数の３次元の図の作図を行なおうとしているのですが、`outer()`関数呼び出し後の自作関数 `GaussianKernel()`の挙動が理解できずエラーが発生してしまいます。その結果scatterplot3dパッケージの３次元作図関数`scatterplot3d()`でもエラーが発生してしまいます。
このRコードでの`outer()`関数、及び`scatterplot3d()`の挙動、及び対策案を教えて頂きたく存じますm(__)m

以下、実装中のRコードです。

```
library( MASS )    # MASS package
library( kernlab ) # 
library( scatterplot3d )  # scatterplot3d関数を使用

#########################
# set gauss kernel
#########################
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# GaussianKernel()
# [in]
#  x1 :       [vector] input data x1-axis
#  x2 :       [vector] input data x2-axis
#  alpha :    [scaler] constant value
#  mean :     [vector] mean vector
#  matSigma : [matrix] covariance matrix
# [out]
#  gauss :    [scaler] function value (z value)
#---------------------------------------------------------------
GaussianKernel <- function( x1, x2, alpha, mean, matSigma )
{
  datX <- c(x1,x2)
  datX <- as.matrix( datX )
  mean <- as.matrix( mean )
#print(datX)
#print(mean)
  gauss <- ( solve( matSigma ) %*% ( datX - mean ) )
#print(gauss)  
  gauss <- ( -alpha*t( datX-mean )%*%gauss ) 
  gauss <- exp( gauss )

  return( gauss )
}

lstGKernel <- list(
  x1 = seq( from=0, to=10, by=0.1 ),
  x2 = seq( from=0, to=10, by=0.1 ),
  z = matrix( 0, nrow = 100, ncol = 100 ),
  
  dat_alpha = 0.005,
  vec_u = c( -7.61,0.22 ),
  matS = matrix( c(0.72,-0.53,-0.53,0.84), nrow = 2, ncol = 2 )
)
```

**このコード呼び出し後の動作が理解できていません。**

```
# outer()で自作関数GaussianKernel()のz軸成分を求める
lstGKernel$z <- outer( 
    lstGKernel$x1, lstGKernel$x2,                      #関数の入力データ引数x1,x2
    GaussianKernel,                                          #対象の自作関数
    lstGKernel$dat_alpha, lstGKernel$vec_u ,lstGKernel$matS  #関数の引数指定
)
```

実行結果

> Error in datX - mean : non-conformable arrays

```
############################
# Draw figure              #
############################
scatterplot3d(
  x = lstGKernel$x1, y = lstGKernel$x2, z =lstGKernel$z,
  main = lstAxis$mainTitle,
#  xlim=lstAxis$xlim, ylim=lstAxis$ylim, zlim = lstAxis$zlim,
  highlight = TRUE
)
```

実行結果

> Error in xyz.coords(x = x, y = y, z = z, xlab = xlabel, ylab = ylabel,
> :    'x', 'y' and 'z' lengths differ

＜17/02/09 追記＞
回答で提示して頂いたコードを元に作図した結果を載せておきます。

①全体図
[image: 全体図]

②x1=x2ラインの輪切り
[image: x1=x2ラインの輪切り]

③特定の範囲
[image: 特定の範囲]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer()`関数の挙動というより，自作関数`GaussianKernel()`内でのデータの扱いでエラー(dimが異なる行列で減算を指示，など)があるように思います。関数内のコードを参考に，以下のような関数を組んでみました:

```
GaussianKernel2 <- function( x1, x2, alpha, mean, matSigma )
{
  datX <- cbind(x1,x2) #cbindで列をキープ
  mean <- matrix(rep(mean, each = nrow(datX)), ncol = ncol(datX)) #datXと同次元の行列へ
  devX <- t(datX - mean) #先に差を計算。ただし以降の計算で使えるよう転置。
  #print(datX)
  #print(mean)
  gauss <- ( solve( matSigma ) %*% devX )
  #print(gauss)  
  gauss <- ( -alpha*t( devX )%*%gauss ) 
  gauss <- exp( gauss )

  return( gauss )
}
```

そして`outer()`を適用せず，この関数だけで，求めたいzの値は得られるのではないかと思います:

```
lstGKernel <- list(
  x1 = seq( from=0, to=10, by=0.1 ),
  x2 = seq( from=0, to=10, by=0.1 ),
  z = matrix( 0, nrow = 100, ncol = 100 ),

  dat_alpha = 0.005,
  vec_u = c( -7.61,0.22 ),
  matS = matrix( c(0.72,-0.53,-0.53,0.84), nrow = 2, ncol = 2 )
)

lstGKernel$z <- GaussianKernel2( 
  lstGKernel$x1, lstGKernel$x2, 
  lstGKernel$dat_alpha, lstGKernel$vec_u ,lstGKernel$matS
)
```

この計算結果から`scatterplot3d()`で作図する方法については，同関数のヘルプにあるexample4が参考になるかと思い，それをベースに作成してみました:

```
# scatterplot3d用データ作成
forPlot <- lstGKernel$z
dimnames(forPlot) <- list(lstGKernel$x1, lstGKernel$x2)
s3d_dat <- data.frame(
  x1=as.vector(col(forPlot)),
  x2=as.vector(row(forPlot)),
  value=as.vector(forPlot)
)
# 作図
scatterplot3d(s3d_dat, type = "h", pch = " ",
              x.ticklabs = colnames(forPlot), y.ticklabs = rownames(forPlot),
              highlight.3d = TRUE)
```

手元では図が表示されるようになりましたが，数学的な処理において間違いがありましたらご指摘いただけると助かります。

Comment: ご回答どうもありがとうございました！回答した頂いた内容を参考に動作確認してみます！

Comment: ガウス核関数のグラフ化出来ました。（`x.ticklabs = colnames(forPlot), y.ticklabs = rownames(forPlot)`の箇所は、`lstGKernel1$x1` `lstGKernel1$x2`の値を描写するように設定）改めて、ご回答どうもありがとうございました！感謝致しますm(__)m

Comment: 因みに、このガウス核関数を作図するRコードを書こうと思ったきっかけは、WEB上にカーネル写像後のデータ分布の図はあれど、カーネル関数自体のグラフが見つからなかったからです。

Comment: 質問に追記した＜17/02/09 追記＞、ガウス核関数のグラフに間違えがあればコメント頂けると助かります。